# Old Ubuntu, new Windows

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, wubi, backup

I've been using Ubuntu 13.04 that was installed inside Windows 8 on my C drive. I did a lot of customization to Ubuntu to make it more beautiful, and had lots of software installed.

I had to reinstall Windows as it got corrupted, and before reinstalling Windows (I did a fresh installation) I made a backup of 'Ubuntu' folder (that's in C drive) hoping that after reinstalling I could manually set a path to wubi to avoid redoing all my efforts to make my Ubuntu as earlier. I used this [How To Restore the Wubi Ubuntu Bootloader](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20340/how-to-restore-the-wubi-ubuntu-bootloader/) tutorial as a reference. 
By doing this I am getting:

```
error: no such device: FOC............. (a long code)
error: unknown filesystem.
error: You need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue.....
```

So, I tried one more thing. I reinstalled Ubuntu on C drive, and replaced the Ubuntu folder by an older one that I took a backup of. Getting:

```
error: no such device: FOC............. (a long code)
error: file '/ubuntu/disks/root.disk' not found

Press any key to continue.....
```

So my question is: Am I thinking of doing some infeasible thing, or is it possible to run old Ubuntu in a new Windows installation. If so, how?

I really want to get my Ubuntu back. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please read this for limitations on using WUBI, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6504/how-do-we-handle-13-04-wubi-questions

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind for response but I use to install ubuntu using cmd 'wubi.exe --force-wbi' and it enables 'install inside windows' option back...  Can you plz lemme know is it possible to restore my old ubuntu inside new windows installaton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there - the problem is that the Wubi `root.disk` remembers the partition that it is installed on via it's `UUID` and since you've gone and reinstalled Windows it has changed.

Wubi boots via a (simplified) two step process. The first is Grub loading the `root.disk` which is generic. Then Grub load the `grub.cfg` (Grub menu) from the `root.disk`. This is where your problem lies.

So you can just hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after selecting Ubuntu and then, once the Grub menu appears, press <kbd>C</kbd> to get to a Grub command prompt: `grub>`.

Enter the following to boot the Wubi install, and then run `sudo update-grub` from a terminal after logging in:

```
search -s -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
probe --set=diskuuid -u $root
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

Comment: Hey bcbc... I am able to get into my ubuntu now...I am so happy... thanks thanks thanks.. u r awesome.......